# scikit-learn CART String Data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Are you able to train a DecisionTreeClassifier with string data?

When I try to use String data I get a ValueError: could not converter string to float

`clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()

clf.fit([['asdf', '1'], ['asdf', '0']], ['2', '3'])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to transform string-valued features to numeric ones in a NumPy array; [`DictVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html) does that for you.

```
samples = [['asdf', '1'], ['asdf', '0']]
# turn the samples into dicts
samples = [dict(enumerate(sample)) for sample in samples]

# turn list of dicts into a numpy array
vect = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
X = vect.fit_transform(samples)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X, ['2', '3'])
```

Remember to use `vect.transform` on the test samples, after converting those to dicts.

Comment: Cool, I 100% support you grabbing the link from my answer and removing the reference to my answer, and then I'll delete my answer.  Yours is better.

Comment: @rrenaud: ok, done that. Feel free to leave your answer around, though.